# efficient way to perform matching of irregular row length by pandas or numpy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I got a table1 to perform matching like vlookup, what is the most efficient to convert the table by numpy or pandas to reconstruct the table like this (using val1 to find the corresponding type and create a new table)?

table 1:

```
| Type | Val1        |
|------|-------------|
| 1    | [d,e,f]     |
| 2    | [a,b,c,d,f] |
| 3    | [a,b,e,f]   |
| 4    | [a,c,d,f]   |
| 5    | [a,b,c,e,f] |
| 6    | [c,f]       |
| 7    | [a,b,c,e,f] |
| 8    | [c,e,f]     |
| 9    | [a,b,c,e]   |
```

expected table:

```
| Val1 | Type              |
|------|-------------------|
| a    | [2,3,4,5,6,9]     |
| b    | [2,3,5,7,9]       |
| c    | [2,4,5,6,7,8,9]   |
| d    | [1,2,4]           |
| e    | [1,3,5,7,8,9]     |
| f    | [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] |
```

Many thanks!

Comment: `Val1` column of your input dataframe is a list or a string?

Comment: For table 1 Val1 column, [d,e,f] and the rest are lists.

Comment: OK. My output is not the same as yours, can you check my answer, please? I got `[2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]` for a and you have `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]`

Comment: Yours is correct, sorry for my typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> df.set_index('Type')['Val1'].explode() \
      .reset_index().groupby('Val1')['Type'] \
      .apply(list).reset_index()

  Val1                      Type
0    a        [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]
1    b           [2, 3, 5, 7, 9]
2    c     [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
3    d                 [1, 2, 4]
4    e        [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]
5    f  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a list comprehension, it is as fast as the pandas' approach (even a tiny bit faster):

```
s = df2.set_index('Type')['Val1']
# get the list of possible values
values = sorted(set([e for l in s.values for e in l]))
# get indices for each value
pd.Series({v: list(s2[s2].index)
           for v in values
           for s2 in [s.apply(lambda x: v in x)]
          }, name='Type').sort_index().rename_axis('Val1').reset_index()
```

output:

```
  Val1                      Type
0    a        [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]
1    b           [2, 3, 5, 7, 9]
2    c     [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
3    d                 [1, 2, 4]
4    e        [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]
5    f  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```